# Passing the Right Element to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm working on a page that should do two things -

1. Fetch data from PHP database and display it row-wise in an HTML table.
2. Allow row-wise editing on the click of the 'edit' button at the last column of each table.

I am not sure how to go about with the second step. I realize that each row created will have elements with the same 'id', thus getElementById is not effective as it returns the first element it finds as a match. What approach could be taken to solve this problem? I've been stuck quite some time now, and am no longer sure if this question is even do-able. Any constructive suggestions would be welcome.

Here's my code snippets.

PHP inside the BODY -

```
echo "<table id='param-table' align='center' style=' border: 1px solid black;'>";
    echo "<tr style=' border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px'>
          <td style=' border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px;'>Param Code</td>
          <td style=' border: 1px solid black;  padding: 15px;'>Param Desc</td>
          <td style='  padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;'>Param Val</td>
          <td style='  padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;'>Edit Param</td><tr>";

    while ($row_users = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo "<form onSubmit='return false;' method='POST'>
              <tr style=' border: 1px solid black;  padding: 15px;'>
              <td style=' border: 1px solid black;  padding: 15px;'>"."
                  <input id='pcode' type='text'  maxlength='10' value='".$row_users['ParamCode']."'>"."
              </td>
              <td style=' border: 1px solid black;  padding: 15px;'>"."
                  <input id='pdesc' type='text'  maxlength='50' value='".$row_users['ParamDesc']."'>"."
              </td>
              <td style=' border: 1px solid black;  padding: 15px;'>"."
                  <input id='pval' type='text'  maxlength='20' value='".$row_users['ParamValue']."'>"."
              </td>
              <td style=' border: 1px solid black;  padding: 15px;'>"."
                  <button onclick='editParam(pcode,pdesc,pval)'>Edit Param</button>"." 
              </td>
              </form>
              </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
```

NOTE : I tried to post an image of what my page looks like to give a better visual idea, but apparently I'm too new to StackOverflow to be allowed to do that. :/

Comment: *"I realize that each row created will have elements with the same 'id', thus getElementById is not effective..."* More importantly, the HTML is **invalid**. You want to fix that before doing anything else.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, how so can the problem be fixed? I am dynamically getting data from the database, and I need an id to access my input. What can be done? I'm in a fix!

Comment: @ user: *"...and I need an id to access my input..."* No, you don't. I was writing an answer showing you how you don't need `id`s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a minimal-changes spirit, here's what you do:

1. Change your `id` values to classes, names, or anything else that's allowed to repeat.
2. Change your `button`'s `onclick` to look like this:

   ```
   <button onclick='editParam(this)'>
   ```

   ...which will pass that *specific* `button` element into the `editParam` function.
3. Then in `editParam`, you can do something like this (see in-code comments):

   ```
   function editParam(button) {
       var tr, pcode, pdesc, pval;

       // Find the row containing these inputs
       tr = button.parentNode;
       while (tr && tr.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "TR" && tr.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "BODY") {
           tr = tr.parentNode;
       }
       if (!tr || tr.nodeName.toUpperCase() !== "TR") {
           return; // Something went wrong
       }

       // Get the inputs for this row -- in this code, I'm using classes,
       // but just change the CSS selector if you use names instead, for
       // instance `pcode = tr.querySelector("input[name=pcode]");`
       pcode = tr.querySelector(".pcode");
       pdesc = tr.querySelector(".pdesc");
       pval  = tr.querySelector(".pval");

       // Use them...
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes! 'this', that was what needed to be done! I've used it in C++ before but never in HTML, so it didn't even cross my mind. Thank you so much @T.J.Crowder!

Comment: @user3714817: :-) You're welcome. This is `this` in JavaScript (and the DOM), not in HTML: Your code in the `onXyz` attribute is run inside a browser-supplied function where `this` is set to the element the `onXyz` attribute is attached to. `this` is a much more flexible concept in JavaScript than in C++ (which tends to confuse people coming from C++ or Java or similar).

Answer (score 0):

Forget about using IDs, while you can dynamically generate them and pass them to the `onclick` attribute, that is more trouble than it is worth.

Use the target of the event to figure out what was clicked, and then navigate up and down the DOM to find what you are looking for.

Here's a [simplified example](http://jsbin.com/tusajigu/2/edit) to show you how it works:

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>foo
      <td>bar
      <td><button type="button">baz</button>
    <tr>
      <td>foo2
      <td>bar2
      <td><button type="button">baz2</button>
    <tr>
      <td>foo3
      <td>bar3
      <td><button type="button">baz3</button>
    <tr>
      <td>foo4
      <td>bar4
      <td><button type="button">baz4</button>
  </table>

  <script>
    function whatRowAmIIn(event) {
      var target = event.target;
      // Do nothing if something other than a button was clicked
      if (target.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "button") {
        return;
      }
      // Figure out which row the button was in
      var tr = target.parentNode.parentNode;
      // Get the bar td (for the sake of example)
      var bar_td = tr.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)');
      alert(bar_td.firstChild.data); 
    }
    document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('click', whatRowAmIIn);
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix the PHP code a bit to have the closing tags </form> after </tr> and I did a little indention for readability

```
<?php
    echo "<table id='param-table' align='center' style=' border: 1px solid black;'>";
    echo "<tr style=' border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px'><td style=' border: 1px solid black; padding: 15px;'>Param Code</td><td style=' border: 1px solid black;  padding: 15px;'>Param Desc</td><td style='  padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;'>Param Val</td><td style='  padding: 15px; border: 1px solid black;'>Edit Param</td><tr>";
    while ($row_users = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
        echo "<form onSubmit='return false;' method='POST'>
                <tr style=' border: 1px solid black;  padding: 15px;'>
                    <td style=' border: 1px solid black;  padding: 15px;'>".
                        "<input id='pcode_".$row_users['ParamCode']."' type='text'  maxlength='10' value='".$row_users['ParamCode']."'>".
                    "</td>
                    <td style=' border: 1px solid black;  padding: 15px;'>".
                        "<input id='pdesc_".$row_users['ParamCode']."' type='text'  maxlength='50' value='".$row_users['ParamDesc']."'>".
                    "</td>
                    <td style=' border: 1px solid black;  padding: 15px;'>".
                        "<input id='pval_".$row_users['ParamCode']."' type='text'  maxlength='20' value='".$row_users['ParamValue']."'>".
                    "</td>
                    <td style=' border: 1px solid black;  padding: 15px;'>".
                        "<button onclick='editParam(".$row_users['ParamCode'].")'>Edit Param</button>".
                    "</td>
                </tr>
            </form>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

On the JS function, use

```
function editParam(rowParamCode)
```

the rowParamCode will have the value for ParamCode for the row that's button was clicked and to get the elements of the rows use

```
document.getElementById("pcode_" + rowParamCode)
document.getElementById("pdesc_" + rowParamCode)
document.getElementById("pval_" + rowParamCode)
```

Hope this helps!